# Handling different success and fail states for multiple ajax call using deferred objects in jQuery

Tags: jquery, deferred

`$.when` returns a Deferred object for all the multiple ajax calls queried simultaneously.

If everything succeeds `.done()` executes and if any one of the url fails `.fail()` executes.

How to handle partial success states? (i.e) if 5 urls are passed to `$.when`, if 3 succeeds we need to handle success state and it 2 fails we need to handle failure state.

```
$.when($.getJSON(headerUrl), $.getJSON(tasksUrl), $.getJSON(testingTrackerUrl), $.getJSON(highlightsUrl)))
    .then(function(headerData, tasksData,testingTrackerData,highlightsData) {
        printData(headerData, tasksData,testingTrackerData,highlightsData);
    })
    .fail(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.error('Got error in '+jqXHR);
});
```

Comment: You can't do that with `$.when`, it creates a master deferred that is resolved when all the underlying promises are resolved, or fails when one of the underlying promises fail. There is no inbetween, if you want to handle different states for different ajax calls, you have to do it individually.

Comment: @adeneo yes I am aware of the fact that there can not be intermediate states. But want to know how to handle partial success and fail states for multiple ajx call. Can we make use of jqXHR readystate and identify the state of each call? Or is there any other way in jQuery?

Comment: You use the appropriate callback for each ajax call.

Comment: @adeneo Need to have the calls asynchronous. Pasted the code snippet above. Please do let me know to proceed in handling callback for each ajax call

Comment: You will essentially have to implement a new version of `$.when()`  (perhaps `$.whenAll()` that doesn't complete until the last promise has finished.  You could even grab the code for `$.when()`, change the function name and modify it slightly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
var request = function (url) {
        return $.getJSON(url)
}
, requests = [
    headerUrl
    , tasksUrl
    , testingTrackerDataUrl
    , highlightsDataUrl
];
// return array of `resolved` , `rejected` jqxhr objects
$.when(
    $.map(requests, function (_request, i) {
         return request(_request)
    })
)
// do stuff with `resolved` , `rejected` jqxhr objects
.always(function (arr) {
    $.each(arr, function (key, value) {
        // `success`
        value.then(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
            console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr);
            printData(data)
        }
        // `error`
        , function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
        })
    })
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/91Lomwr3/