# Error Handling and Recovery with jQuery Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I am using jQuery and am aware that this issue is because the jQuery.Deferred implementation is not Promises/A+ compiant. I do not want to use any other libraries to solve this.

With that out of the way, is there a way to recover from a `$.Deferred().fail()` callback such that I am returned back to the success chain? This is possible with the multi-callback form of `then()` but so far I have not found a solution using `.fail()`

then:

```
asyncThatWillFail().then(function () {
    // useless callback
}, function () {
    console.log("error");
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
}).then(function () {
    console.log("continuing on success chain");
});
```

fail (does not work):

```
asyncThatWillFail().fail(function () {
    console.log("error");
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
}).then(function () {
    console.log("continuing on success chain");
});
```

In my case I only need to check for failure, set a flag, and continue with what I was doing. I simply don't need the parallel success handler in the "then" example.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/86d29j1L/2/) to further clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use `.fail` for that. However, you don't need to pass a function as the first argument to [`.then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/):

> the arguments can be `null` if no callback of that type is desired.

Since only `then` enables chaining, you should use

```
asyncThatWillFail().then(null, function () {
    console.log("error");
    return $.Deferred().resolve();
}).then(function () {
    console.log("continuing on success chain");
});
```

Apart from the need to return a fulfilled jQuery promise, this is just like the [ES6 `then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method where [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) is a synonym for `.then(null, …)`.